# Making lines from nodes using OpenStreetMap and PostGIS (+ TileMill)

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, tilemill

using openstreetmap data (in a postgis database), I would like to highlight all roads with a certain `surface` tag in tilemill.

I can query for the tag, doing

```
SELECT * FROM planet_osm_ways WHERE 'cobblestone'=any(tags)
```

which returns `id`, `nodes`, `tags`:

```
24204652    {262087470,262087665,262087666} {highway,residential,maxspeed,30,name,Landréstraße,postal_code,12621,surface,cobblestone}
...
```

I'm not sure how to proceed though, as tilemill expects *geometry*. I suppose, I somehow have to look up each id in `nodes` and combine everything to lines(?).

---

**update:**

I *think* I managed to make linestrings from node coordinates, doing

```
SELECT way_id, st_makeline(coord) AS way 
    INTO __test
    FROM (SELECT b.id AS way_id, ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(lon, lat), 3857) AS coord
        FROM (SELECT id, unnest(nodes) AS node_id FROM planet_osm_ways WHERE 'cobblestone'=any(tags)) a 
        INNER JOIN planet_osm_nodes b 
            ON a.node_id=b.id
        ORDER BY way_id
    ) c
    GROUP BY way_id
```

[image]

but in tilemill nothing shows up.

---

**update 2:**

after adjusting the layer settings in tilemill, I'm getting an error now:

```
Detected out of bounds geographic extent (180,85.0511287798066,180,85.051) for layer 'cobblestone'. Please ensure that the SRS for this layer is correct. Its native extent is '686159783,145786972,692158671,153144983'
```

[image]

Comment: The id should correspond to another table which would have a `geometry` data type. Do you have a table with linestring geometry, perhaps called `ways`? If so, the value in `id` probably corresponds to that geometry. You can then do a table join, see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have a geom, you should be able to add the layer on Tilemill. Enter your request, surrounded by `( ...you request... ) as my_table` (the name is not important, but you need one).

Be sure, when you add your postgis layer, to enter `way_id` as your unique id, `way` as your geometry, and you select the good SRS (by default it should be 900913, which is the old id for 3857 so it should be ok). Then press save & style and you should be able to see it.

If you don't, even if you don't have any error, and even after waiting some time, maybe try with only a few way_id to be sure that it's not a performance issu.

**Update 2:** if you look and the data (the table), you indeed have values over the limit. The raison is most probably because there is a problem with your SRID: using ST_SetSRID does **NOT** project the geom, it just set the SRID field inside the geom. When you use `ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(lon, lat), 3857)` you have a point in `4326`, and you say it's in `3857`. Either use `ST_Transform` instead of `ST_SetSRID`, or simply set it instead to `4326` and set the SRS in Tilemill on `WSG84` (which is the srid 4326).